# Вставка данных из БД в форму

Tags: php

Добрый день всем. Плохо разбираюсь в РНР. но нужно вставить данные

так я получаю данные

```
$id=$_GET['mess_id'];
$sql='SELECT * FROM tb_message WHERE tb_message.id="'.$id.'"';
$res=mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
```

но незнаю как вставить их в

```
input type="text" size="30" name="title"
```

заранее спасибо.

Comment: Изучайте [второй][1] вариант. Возможно это натолкнет вас на решение

И пока это не увидел @eicto, обратите внимание на предупреждение в самом начале страницы ;-)

  [1]: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php#refsect1-function.mysql-query-examples

Comment: Товарищем @eicto скоро будут пугать непослушных детей :)

Answer (score 1):

Как то так можно попробовать:

```
$id=$_GET['mess_id'];
$sql='SELECT * FROM tb_message WHERE tb_message.id="'.$id.'"';
$res=mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
 foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
  echo "<input type="text" name="$key" value="$val" />";
 }
}
```

Нужные поля можно выбрать в SQL запросе: перечислить вместо `*` через запятую, что то наподобие:

```
SELECT name, lastname, address, zip FROM tb_message WHERE...
```

Comment: Один маленький, но важный момент:

если $_GET['mess_id'] должно быть числом:
$id = (int)$_GET['mess_id'];

если строкой, то:
$id = htmlentities($_GET['mess_id']);

Можно еще обвернуть в mysql_escape_string(), но это уже на ваше усмотрение

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = $_GET['mess_id'];
if (!is_numeric($id)) exit;
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tb_message WHERE tb_message.id = "' . $id . '" LIMIT 1';
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$message = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
<input type="text" size="30" name="title" value="<?php print $message['тут поле из БД']; ?>">
```

Обязательно почитайте что такое SQL иньекция.